# Trying to e-mail a SharePoint calendar from Outlook, limited to 2800 appointments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, sharepoint

I have SharePoint 2010 calendar that I've connected to Microsoft Outlook 2010. I right-clicked the calendar in Outlook and selected Share -> E-mail, but when attaching the calendar, I receive this warning:

> The calendar cannot contain more than 2800 appointments. Shorten the date range, and then try again.

[image]

This seems a little vague. Does it mean I can only send a calendar with 2800 appointments, or that the calendar itself shouldn't ever contain more than 2800 appointments in general? I couldn't find any documentation from Microsoft about such a limit.